# How do I horizontally scroll code on the iPad?

Tags: discussion, ipad, browsers

When I use iPad to browse this site, there is no horizontal bar where program code is displayed.  What technology was behind this incompatibility issue.  Was it Flash?

Comment: When was the last time they allowed all members of the Justice League of the Superboy punch on an iPad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe no scrollbars are ever visible on an iPad other than the main viewport. However, you can <strike>hold one finger down on an area that scrolls and use another finger to scroll that area</strike> use the "Two finger scroll" to view the content (provided you know that it scrolls). This [works for me](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/03/the-works-on-my-machine-certification-program.html) on my iPad.

See [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3890400/problems-with-div-vertical-scrollbars-on-ipad) for more technical information...

Comment: this is called "two finger scroll", I have never heard it described in the manner you are describing it :p

Comment: @Jeff, thanks for clearing that up...makes more sense...i'm likely an island iPad user...